# SharePoint 2016 on-prem Sync doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

So, according to [Microsoft articles](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sync-sharepoint-files-with-the-onedrive-for-business-sync-client-groove-exe-59b1de2b-519e-4d3a-8f45-51647cf291cd), SharePoint 2016 can only sync files for offline use with groove.exe.  Those connections must be initiated from OneDrive for Business (groove client) by pasting the library URL.  If this is the case, how can I hide the Sync button in each library and in the ribbon?

[Additional reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-install-the-onedrive-for-business-sync-client-with-office-and-sharepoint-37b3dddd-30af-4294-aba8-c290cea01b5d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: It's not the case that those connections must be initiated from OneDrive for Business Groove Client. It's possible to hit the sync button as well. I'm a little confused with your question. What's the exact reason why you want to hide the sync button?

Comment: @engineerer Because the Sync button isn't working and after only finding the above linked info from MS stating that you have to initiate from grove, I thought hope was lost.